# how to filter views based user access to objects

Tags: performance

I am newbie and have a design question.
The question may be vauge but I will try anyway.

Assume that we 2500 file objects in the system. We have users that have access to certain files.

When we display different view of files or objects associated to files we need filter the view depending on the logged in users access to files. If every view requires the application to run through all files I guess it is bad for peformance. What is general practice to handle such situations? Make a cache of the files the logged user has access to?

This is a general question but I can still add that we are using MySQL and Hibernate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you works with 2500 files - then probably it's not a problem for performance. Amount is't very big. But numbers could grows faster.

So as I see you use some relational database. Create a table for your files (Files), create a tables for your user (Users) and UserFileMapping table (to store user to file relation). Your goal is to implement many-to-many relation with user-to-files. This is [tutorial](http://return-true.com/2011/02/mysql-many-to-many-relationships/) how to implement it.

Then you could query all files per user with simple expression like 
`Select distinct from Files inner join FilesUserMapping on File.ID == FilesUserMapping.FileID  where FilesUserMapping.UserID == 'your_user_id'` (query is very approximate, I'm not working with sql for a long time and forget a lot of the stuff)

It will return all the files for your user and will made it in very effective manner, because databases have very good optimization.